# Pulling colored balls from a bag

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Balls are randomly removed from a bag without replacement. If the probability that the first five balls withdrawn are all green is one-half, what is the fewest possible number of balls in the bag at the start?

I believe the answer is 10 balls because we can assume that there are 5 green balls to begin with. Does this logic hold?

Comment: No.  If there are $10$ balls, $5$ of which are green, the probability that the first five are green is $1\big /\binom {10}5\neq \frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu thank you that is what I was thinking. I will keep working on this problem

Comment: But if there are $10$ balls, $9$ of which are green, then the probability that the first five are green is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A difference of $1$ ball between green balls and $n$ will yield the minimum $n$ providing it has a whole number solution, so .........

$$\frac{\binom{n-1}{5}}{\binom{n}{5}} = \frac{(\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-6)!5!})}{(\frac{n!}{(n-5)!5!})} = \frac{(n-1)!(n-5)!5!}{(n-6)!5!n!} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{(n-1)!(n-5)!}{(n-6)!n!} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{(n-5)}{n} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$2n - 10 = n$$

$$n = 10$$